# SQL CE Compact Edition Toolbox OutOfMemoryException

Tags: sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-toolbox

I get OutOfMemoryException when i click Edit Top 200 Rows on a Table.
I opened an 52,396 KB size sdf file.

How can i open it?

[image]

UPDATE:
If i reopen the VS 2019 it works without problem. :)

Comment: "*when i click Edit Top 200 Rows on a Table*" - how is this related to C#?

Comment: Very likely that class or project has some memory handling issues. It is hard to help with just the screenshot of the `OutOfMemoryException`

Comment: I would either debug it (requires the PDB or disassembly) or use a memory profiler.

Comment: Email me the database privately, and I will have a look - I am the tool maintainer